# Show that $x,y \text{ and } z$ are linear independent iff $x \times y, x \times z \text{ and } y \times z$ are linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

> Let $ x,y,z \in{\mathbb R}^3$. Show that $x,y \text{ and } z$ are linear independent iff  $x \times y,
>  x \times z \text{ and } y \times z$ are linear independent. Where
>   $\times$ denotes the cross product in ${\mathbb R}^3.$

So far I have only been able to show the forward implication: If $x,y,z$ are linear dependent, then  $x \times y, x \times z \text{ and } y \times z$ are also linear dependent.

I need help with the backwards implication:
If  $x \times y, x \times z \text{ and } y \times z$ are  linear independent, then $x,y,z$ are linear independent

I would be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the cross products are linearly independent. Suppose $ax+by+cz=0$ so $ax\times y + cz\times y =0$. Hence $a=c=0$. Similarly you can prove $b=0$. Since no non-zero choices of $a,\,b,\,c$ work, $x,\,y,\,z$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
det \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2 & a_3 b_1-a_1 b_3 & a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1 \\
b_2 c_3-b_3 c_2 & b_3 c_1-b_1 c_3 & b_1 c_2-b_2 c_1 \\
c_2 a_3-c_3 a_2 & c_3 a_1-c_1 a_3 & c_1 a_2-c_2 a_1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
det \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}